# Deploy C# code that has reference to Npgsql dll

Tags: c#, deployment, npgsql

.Net 4.8, C#, Npgsql, .NET 7.0

We add an access to PostgreSQL to an existing app .Net 4.8 .
How we did it? Just right click on "References" ->> "Manage NuGet Packages..."

In order to deploy, we have now a high number of dependent DLLs and XMLs (see a picture of a debug directory).

Question: how to minimize a number of artifacts (DLLs, XMLs ) **to deploy**?
[image]

Comment: [Publish single file app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=vs#publish-a-single-file-app)

Comment: _".Net 4.8, C#, Npgsql, .NET 7.0"_ - I'm confused, is this a question about .NET Framework 4.8 or _NET 7_?

Comment: No confusion.
4.8 Existing code
7.0 Npgsql

Answer (score 3):

XMLs should not be deployed.

For Npgsql, you need Npgsql.dll and Mono.Security.dll

Others .NET framework DLLs are needed only if your deployment isn't framework dependant, otherwise your app will expect to find them on the computer it runs on.

Comment: Thank you @Luca
Yes, when using version 2.7 of Npgsql - only two dlls
But there is an error when connect 
"only authentication clear text password and authentication md5 password supported for now. received 10"

Comment: That is not an error, is a known limitation of that version

Comment: How to fix the error?

Comment: Upgrade if you can or using clear text/MD5 password. You can change it in your server pg_hba.conf file https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html
Remember to restart postgres service after changes